# psycopg2 is not install on MAC

Tags: python-2.7

ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
ERROR: running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

Error: pg_config executable not found.

pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
<http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-u0_Pdy/psycopg2/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for people to be able to help you, you need to provide some context. What is it that you are trying to do and during which step does the issue occur? See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask